# Declaration of an array valid for zsh and bash

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, zsh

I am looking for a way to declare an array that will work in bash and zsh.

I know I can do simply this in bash:

```
file_list=$(example_command)
```

And in zsh I can make it work like this:

```
file_list=($(example_command))
```

I know I can just do it with an if statement if I want to, but hope to do it without:

```
if [ `basename $SHELL`=bash ]; then
    file_list=$(example_command)
elif [ `basename $SHELL`=zsh ]; then 
    file_list=($(example_command))
else
    echo "ERROR: UNKNOWN SHELL"
fi
```

I do not really care about other shells (eg sh). Just looking for something working in zsh and bash which is not too exotic looking.

Comment: What are you actually doing? [Surely you're not actually getting a list of files using `$(ls)`?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)  What about something like `declare -a file_list; n=1; for f in *; do file_list[$((n++))]="$f"; done`? Does the same thing in both bash and zsh, if you need to control the numbering of your keys a little more precisely.

Comment: `file_list=( * )` is the right way to put a list of files into an array.

Comment: As for ```[ `basename $SHELL`=bash ]```, that's bad syntax in any shell. Needs spaces around the `=`; if you just pass `test` a single word, what it's testing is whether that word is empty or not, and if the output from `basename` has no spaces, you're testing whether something like `zsh=bash` is non-empty, so it's true, even if you *want* it to be false.

Comment: `file_list=$(ls)` isn't creating an array in bash at all, btw; it's just assigning the output of `ls` to a string. If you want to create an array in bash via string-splitting and glob expansion (which you shouldn't -- the globbing side of this behavior is usually unwanted and results in buggy scripts), it's the same syntax as in zsh, `file_list=( $(...) )`

Comment: No I am not. I am actually running a different command than `ls`. It was just an example. I will edit for clarity.

Comment: Not to mention that the subshell could be replaced with `${SHELL##*/}` to strip the variable POSIXly, and iirc zsh doesn't update the `$SHELL` variable. If you need to detect whether you're in zsh, perhaps check the `$ZSH_NAME` variable before checking `$SHELL`.

Comment: Might I ask how you're expanding the array? `echo $array` or `for item in $array` only emits the first element in bash, but emits all of them in zsh. So the problem might not be in how you're **creating** the array, but in how you're **using** it.

Comment: `SHELL` should contain the user's login shell, which is **not** necessarily the currently running shell. `zsh` does not touch the parameter `SHELL` at all, while `bash` will set it to the user's login shell (again, not necessarily `bash`) if it is not already set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumptions about bash are wrong. `file_list=$(example_command)` **does not** create an array there. `file_list=( $(example_command) )` **does** create an array in both shells, though it's not good practice to do so (can't deal with files with spaces, files whose names could be expanded as a glob, etc).

The following is a good-practice approach (insofar as you *can* call handling filenames in a newline-delimited stream good-practice when newlines can be literals in filenames) that works in both shells:

```
file_list=( )
while IFS= read -r line; do file_list+=( "$line" ); done < <(example_command)
```

Importantly, to *use* an array in a way that works in both shells, you need to expand it as `"${file_list[@]}"`, not `$file_list`.

Comment: I did not expanded the array correctly. Thanks for your answer, now trying to understand the good practice method, because I do work with filenames.

Comment: The safe way to handle arbitrary filenames is as a NUL-delimited stream, as created by `printf '%s\0' *`, or `find -print0`, or the like -- as a NUL cannot exist inside a filename, this guarantees that no name can be formed in such a way as to split into multiple other names when serialized to and deserialized from a stream. To `read` them safely, use `while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do`

Comment: ...as an example of a potentially malicious name, btw, consider what's created by `mkdir -- $'/tmp/\n/etc/passwd\n/'`, which could cause a `find /tmp` to have `/etc/passwd` and `/` in its output.

Comment: We don't have such malicious names on our system, but we might have names with spaces.

Comment: The worst data loss event I was present for was caused  by someone writing a script that would handle data files created by an application they controlled, and assuming those files would have names that would only ever match `[0-9a-f]{24}`, so they didn't bother to use safe practices in their scripts. That was fine, until a Python library used to generate the files had a bug in one of its C modules that overwrote a buffer to put a whitespace-surrounded `*` into a filename. The script tried to delete that file when it got old enough to rotate out, and deleted the rest of the backup store also.

Comment: ...so, the point of the story above is that it's always wise to write code defensively, without assuming that other subsystems will behave as expected/intended in generating inputs. I really like the NSA's design terminology here, describing any component whose failure can cause the larger system to break as "trusted"; a defensively-designed and implemented system trusts as little as possible.